# cURLでjsonを取得できない。

Tags: php

phpでcURLを使って以下のコードでiTuneのsearch apiを呼び出しましたがタイムアウトになってしまいます。
cURLはインストールされています。 タイムアウト時間を設定しなくても結果は同じでした。
解決方法を教えて下さい。よろしくおねがいします。

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  require_once 'functions.php';

  switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    case 'GET':
      if(isset($_GET['term'])&&isset($_GET['country'])){
        $url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?';
         $url=$url."term=".$_GET['term']."&country=".$_GET['country'];
         if(isset($_GET['media'])) $url=$url."&media=".$_GET['media'];
         if(isset($_GET['entity'])) $url=$url."&entity=".$_GET['entity'];
         if(isset($_GET['lang'])) $url=$url."&lang=".$_GET['lang'];
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
         $response = curl_exec($ch);
         $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
         $code = $header['http_code'];
         if($code>=400){
           header("HTTP", true, $code);
           echo json_encode($response);
           exit();
         }else{
           echo json_encode($response);
           curl_close($ch);
         }
       }else{
        sendError("Term and country parameter are essential.");
       }
       break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

使っていたネットワークがProxyを通していたのでできなかったようです。

Answer (score 0):

functions.phpにてどのような処理をしているか不明ですが、
私の環境で下記のようなソースにて実行したところ問題なく取得出来ました。

json_encodeしているところをjson_decodeに変更したのと、

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

を追加しています。

```
<?php
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=jp&term=test';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
$code = $header['http_code'];

if($code>=400){
    header("HTTP", true, $code);
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}else{
    var_dump( json_decode(trim($response)) );
    curl_close($ch);
}
```